# Lexus GS300 - Sound of air escaping

Tags: noise

I have a Lexus GS300. Couple weeks ago I sent it to a Toyota dealer for maintenance. In addition to regular maintenance, they said the brake needs change and so I agreed.

This week I found something strange, after I park the car at garage, I hear some air squeezing sound, the sound is like air leaking from a balloon, but maybe a little bit lighter. I am not 100% positive, but I think the sound is from the tires. The sound lasts maybe half minute. The thing is I can hear it almost every day when I come home and park it at my garage at night. In the morning, I park the car at the parking lot, not sure if it is because the environment noise is loud, I do not hear it. I never notice this problem before on this car.

Do you think this is something worth a mechanic to check out? I do not notice any problem yet, but I am pretty dumb at car mechanics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running your defrost, this sound could very well be the refrigerant equalizing in the A/C system. For most cars in the US, when running your defroster, the A/C comes on to dry the air so your windshield will defog. It allows you to see quicker through your windshield as well as not allowing the moisture in your breath to freeze on the inside of the windshield if it is cold enough outside. What I've described is about the only thing which would make this sort of a noise short of a flat tire. If a tire was leaking loud enough for you to hear it, it would be flat. If you are not seeing any difference in the tire ride height, I really doubt you're having any problems there.